# PHP mysqli_query() ,Second connection issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get a "select option, dropdown menu" in PHP to work taking data from MySQL table.
The following code is displaying me correctly the full list of my table "comunas" (one ID number, one description VARCHAR), also is inserting properly the data to the Data Base the first time.
But after submiting the first time (pressing "Send" button), the webpage is failing on me with the warning and not displaying me Dropdown menu id="comuna" the second time:

Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in F:\proyectosFelipe\proyectosPaginas\mantenedor\clienteAdd.php on line 37
Could not connect to MySQL:

I am requiring once require_once mysqli_connect.php in clienteAdd.php and clientForm.php
I think that my issue is related that the second time that the webpage is loaded, is not able to connect to the database, but I am not able to figure out why.
Could you please, guide me to solve my issue, please?

Thank you in advance,

This is the portion of the code that I understand is not ok, because if I take that away, it will not generate me the issue:

```
<?php
    $select = "";
    require_once('mysqli_connect.php');
    //include('mysqli_connect.php');
    $sql=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT  id
                                   ,comuna
                               FROM comunas") OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql))
    {
        //$select= "<select name='comuna' id='comuna' tabindex='6' value='$comuna'>";
        $select= "<select name='comuna' id='comuna' tabindex='6'>";
        $select.='<option value="">Comuna...</option>';
        while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
            $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'. $rs['comuna'] .'</option>';
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($dbc);
    $select.='</select>';
    echo utf8_encode($select);
?>
```

My full code below:

clienteAdd.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Client</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="clienteShow.php">Show Client</a><br>
        <a href="clienteSearch.php">Search Client</a>

        <?php //include('mysqli_connect.php');
              include('clientForm.php');
        ?>
        <div id="divAgenda"> 
        <form id="contact" action="<?= htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) ?>" method="post" name = "registration">
            <div class="success"><?= $success ?></div>
            <fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $rut_error ?></span><br>
                <input placeholder="Rut..." id="rut" type="text" name="rut" value="<?= $rut ?>" tabindex="1" size="8" maxlength="8"> - <input type="text" name="dv" value="<?= $dv ?>" size="1" tabindex="2" maxlength="1">  Ejemplo: 12345678-1<br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $first_name_error ?></span><br>
                <input placeholder="Primer Nombre..." type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name" value="<?= $first_name ?>" maxlength="50" tabindex="3"><br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $last_name_error ?></span><br>
                <input placeholder="Segundo Nombre..." type="text" id="last_name" name="last_name" value="<?= $last_name ?>" maxlength="50" tabindex="4"><br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $email_error ?></span><br>
                <input placeholder="Correo Electrónico..." id="email" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" maxlength="100" tabindex="5"><br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $comuna_error ?></span><br>
                <?php
                    $select = "";
                    require_once('mysqli_connect.php');
                    //include('mysqli_connect.php');
                    $sql=mysqli_query($dbc,"SELECT  id
                                                   ,comuna
                                               FROM comunas") OR die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql))
                    {
                        //$select= "<select name='comuna' id='comuna' tabindex='6' value='$comuna'>";
                        $select= "<select name='comuna' id='comuna' tabindex='6'>";
                        $select.='<option value="">Comuna...</option>';
                        while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
                        {
                            $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'. $rs['comuna'] .'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                    mysqli_close($dbc);
                    $select.='</select>';
                    echo utf8_encode($select);
                ?>
                <br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <span class="error"><?= $address_error ?></span><br>
                <input placeholder="Dirección..." id="address" type="text" name="address" value="<?= $address ?>" maxlength="200" tabindex="5"><br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <span class="respuesta"><?= $codigosValores ?></span><br>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Send</button>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
        <?php 
            if ($rut_error != '')
                echo "<script>(document.getElementById('rut').focus())();</script>";
                else 
                    if ($first_name_error != '')
                    {
                        echo "<script>(document.getElementById('first_name').focus())();</script>";
                    }
                    else
                        if ($last_name_error != '')
                        {
                            echo "<script>(document.getElementById('last_name').focus())();</script>";
                        }
                        else
                            if ($email_error != '')
                            {
                                echo "<script>(document.getElementById('email').focus())();</script>";
                            }
                            else 
                                if ($address_error != '')
                                {
                                    echo "<script>(document.getElementById('address').focus())();</script>";
                                }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

clientForm.php

```
<?php 

// define variables and set to empty values
$rut_error = $first_name_error = $last_name_error = $email_error = $address_error = $comuna_error = "";
$rut = $dv = $first_name = $last_name = $email = $address = $comuna = "";
$error = 0;
$success = "";
$codigosValores = "";

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //RUT Validation
    $rut = test_input($_POST["rut"]);
    $dv  = ($_POST["dv"]);
    if ( empty($_POST["rut"]))
    {
        $rut_error = "RUT is required";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else if ( $dv=='' )
    {
        $rut_error = "Verification digit is required";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else if (!is_numeric($rut))
    {
        $rut_error = "Entered RUT is not numeric";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else if (!((strlen($rut) == 7) or (strlen($rut) == 8)))
    {
        $rut_error = "Number of digits of RUT not valid";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $x = 2; $s = 0; $dv2 = 0;
        for($i = (strlen($rut) - 1); $i >= 0; $i--)
        {
            if($x > 7)
                $x = 2;
            $s += ($rut[$i] * $x);
            $x++;
        }
        $dv2=11-($s % 11);
        if($dv2 == 10)
            $dv2 = 'K';
        if($dv2 == 11)
            $dv2 = '0';
        if($dv2 == $dv)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            $rut_error = "invalid RUT";
            $error = 1;
        }
    }

    //First name Validation
    if (empty($_POST["first_name"]))
    {
        $first_name_error = "First name is required";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $first_name = test_input($_POST["first_name"]);
    }
    //Last name Validation
    if (empty($_POST["last_name"]))
    {
        $last_name_error = "Second name is required";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $last_name = test_input($_POST["last_name"]);
    }
    //Email Validation
    if (empty($_POST["email"]))
    {
        $email_error = "Email is required";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if ((!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) and $rut_error == '' and $first_name_error == '' and $last_name_error == '')
        {
            $email_error = "Invalid email";
            $error = 1;
        }
    }

    //Adress Validation
    if (empty($_POST["address"]))
    {
        $address_error = "Address is required";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $address = test_input($_POST["address"]);
    }

    //Comuna Validation
    if (empty($_POST["comuna"]))
    {
        $comuna_error = "Comuna is required";
        $error = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $comuna = test_input($_POST["comuna"]);
    }
    $codigosValores = "<br>". "rut={" . $rut ."-" . $dv . "}";
    $codigosValores = $codigosValores  . "    ". "first_name={" . $first_name . "}";
    $codigosValores = $codigosValores  . "    ". "last_name={"  . $last_name  . "}";
    $codigosValores = $codigosValores  . "    ". "email={"      . $email      . "}";
    $codigosValores = $codigosValores  . "    ". "address={"    . $address    . "}";
    $codigosValores = $codigosValores  . "    ". "comuna={"     . $comuna     . "}";

    if ($error == 0)
    {
        //include('mysqli_connect.php');
        require_once('mysqli_connect.php');
        $query = "INSERT INTO students (rut, dv, first_name, last_name, email, address, comuna) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $rut, $dv, $first_name, $last_name, $email, $address, $comuna);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);


        if($affected_rows == 1)
        {
            $rut = $dv = $first_name = $last_name = $email = $address = $comuna = '';

            $success = "Customer successfuly inserted.";
            echo "<br>"."Client Entered";
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
            mysqli_close($dbc);
        }
            else
            {
                echo 'Error Occurred<br />';
                echo mysqli_error();
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
                mysqli_close($dbc);
            }

    }
}

function test_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Guessing it's your `mysqli_close($dbc);` closing the database connection before the page has finished execution.

Comment: Thank you so much cOle2, that was the reason, I've just commented my mysqli_close in clientForm.php and now is working fine! :) How shall I give you my vote?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Your `test_input` function serves no useful purpose other than to trash input data. Do escaping *if and when* it's necessary, not in advance. When displaying in HTML use `htmlspecialchars`. Store things in the database as raw as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much Tadman for your comments, I have deleted test_input, I tested and it was not required for me, I will study about the mysqli object oriented and see if I cann applied to my code, thanks in advance:)